# Simple Bison file that keeps getting syntax 1.1 error

Tags: bison, yacc

A simple bison program that upon compilation, I get the error 1.1: syntax error, unexpected end of file. Bison: input/output error. I compile it using bison -d hw3.y

The code is as follows:

```
 %{
    #include <stdio.h>
 %}
 %token NUMBER
 %left '+' '-'
 %left '*' '/'

 %%
 input
     : /* allow empty input */
     | input line
     ;
 line
     : expr '\n' { printf("Result is %f\n", $1); }
 expr
     : expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
     | expr '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
     |    term { $$ = $1; }
     ;
 term
     : term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     |   term '/' factor { $$ = $1 / $3; }
     | factor { $$ = $1; }
     ;
 factor
     : '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
     | NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
     | '-' NUMBER { $$ = -$2; }
     ; 
  %%


   /* display error message */
   int yyerror( char *errmsg ) { printf("%s\n", errmsg); }
   /* main */
    int main() {
     printf("type an expression:\n");
    yyparse( );
   }
```

Comment: _When_ do you get that error? When running Bison, when compiling the resulting C code, or perhaps when you run the parser? If it is when running Bison, I don't see that error when I try to run your code through Bison. Which version of Bison are you using? Are you sure this is the exact code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `;` in the production for `line`. Please note this better way of formatting these files, which exposes this error instantly. Check your braces and comments for correct closure, also quoted strings and characters.

Comment: Bison doesn't require semicolons (and neither does yacc, as per posix). If the `%}` line really starts with a space as in the unedited OP, then it might not be recognized as terminating the code block.